# How to achieve theiremial@theirdomain.com via mydomain.org using AWS SES?

Tags: amazon-ses, emailrelay

I have a use case and questions on top of that

1. I have an active subscription of AWS SES.
   2, I have an app on which customer subscribe and they would like to send emails for donation to their audience.
2. What we want is to use their email id in "From" email + "via mydomai.org" e.g. From "theiremial@theirdomain.com via mydomain.org".
3. Can I do above using SES?
4. Would like to know if #3 is a valid scenario and what are pros & cons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but it's bit complex.

1. AWS SES requires that in a email, From, Mail from and Return path must be verified so your customer email address should be verified on SES.
2. Once the Email address of customer is verified, you also verify your domain and enable DKIM, custom mail from for your email.
3. When you send email, make sure that you use "Mail from" or "Envelope From" address if of your domain and in the From header, you put customer's email address. This way recipients will see the From address (from your customer) and since the DKIM etc are of your domain added by SES (because mail from was of your domain and used as SES identity), they will see via (your domain), Additionally some mail client reads X-Sender to show Via information so you can add "X-Sender: your domain email address" in the email.

Problems:

1. You need to verify your customer's email address in SES
2. Email may end up in spam if recipient has strict policy to match mail from and From header, specially the DMARC (in any case SES default or custom mail from) will fail because mail from and From header domain won't match.   (only if your customer, the From header domain has publish any DMARC record for their domain).